# Authentication strava with react-native-app-auth?

Tags: react-native, strava

In my projects, i have integrated  the packages "react-native-app-auth" with strava to authenticate.

```
  const openStravaApp = async () => {
    const config = {
      clientId: '62069',
      clientSecret: '795dad2fc3d5f3ec9277b6a84f1f49cd7dcb324e',
      redirectUrl: 'com.exam://com.exam',
      serviceConfiguration: {
        authorizationEndpoint: 'https://www.strava.com/oauth/mobile/authorize',
        tokenEndpoint:
          'https://www.strava.com/oauth/token?client_id=62069&client_secret=795dad2fc3d5f3ec9277b6a84f1f49cd7dcb324e',
      },
      scopes: ['activity:read_all'],
    };
    const result = await authorize(config);
  };
```

But I got [image]. What did I do wrong